# If cell contains 3 specific characters, remove those characters, if not, add those characters

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

If InStr(1, c, "+") Then
For Each c In Selection
c.Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
c.Replace What:=")", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
c.Replace What:="+", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next c
End If

For Each c In Selection
If c.Value <> "" Then c.Value = "+" & c.Value
c.Replace " ", " +"
Next

For Each d In Selection
If d.Value <> "" Then d.Value = "(" & d.Value & ")"
Next d
End Sub
```

I am trying to create a toggle since my Add-In will not show and I cannot seem to figure out how to place it in the Add-In screen. Searched high and low and others seem to have the same issue. So, besides that wonderful problem, I cannot seem to figure out how to create a toggle with the button that somehow made it to the Add-In.

All I want is to say:

**If you find** "+" or "(" or ")" then **remove those characters** from the cells otherwise if you **DO NOT find** those characters in the cell, **add them at specific places**. So this should be the scenario:

> Original String: Hello World
>
> Click Once: (+Hello +World) 
>   Click Twice: Hello World

Please help I am going crazy here.

Thank you all!

Comment: Where does it make an error? And which error? If there is no error, what is your output?

Comment: I get a Run-time error 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set) at the "If InStr(1, c, "+") Then" section. Not sure what in the world that means or what I am supposed to do. I have tried to rewrite this in many ways but my limited VBA skills are hindering me from being successful -_-

Comment: Ok, I just posted an answer, but I'll correct it in a few secs to get this right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just misplaced your `End If` so every time you were addind the characters, even if they were already there in the first place!

And you also misplaced the `For each c` , therefore "c" wasn't set and couldn't be used!

*Take the **habit of incrementing** your code so it's more readable*, you won't have that kind of problem! ;)

Give this a try (I added the other characters tests) :

```
    Sub Test()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Selection
    If InStr(1, c, "+") Or InStr(1, c, "(") Or InStr(1, c, ")") Then
        c.Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        c.Replace What:=")", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        c.Replace What:="+", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Else
            If c.Value <> "" Then c.Value = "+" & c.Value
            c.Replace " ", " +"

            If c.Value <> "" Then c.Value = "(" & c.Value & ")"
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, not only does this work and make me smile and jump like a maniac, you were kind enough to give suggestions for my future code writing. Wonderfully written. Thank you. Truly appreciate all the input. I will have to start studying more, I really like this stuff and it's bothering me that I do not know so much.

Comment: hehe no problem! ;)
It's a pleasure to share and help people that are trying to improve! I still need to learn too! Go learn about arrays in VBA (simple `Dim TestArray()` is enough, and the ubound and lbound) and press F2 in VBA dev environment to go to Object Explorer (super helpful), or press F1 to prompt help on the "selectioned" function
As you don't know SO much, you can mark your issue as solved by ticking the gray arrow under down vote, on the top left of each answer, it'll go green! ;)
And up vote things that are useful to make them more visible for others!
Enjoy this awesome site!

Comment: ahah you did it in between^^
See ya

Answer (score 0):

c is not yet defined when you first try to run a function on its value.

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

If InStr(1, c, "+") Then
For Each c In Selection
```

Tested, working variant, somewhat optimised too.

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Selection
    If InStr(1, c, "+") Then 'if it has a plus sign
        c.Value2 = Replace(Replace(Replace(c.Value2, "(", ""), ")", ""), "+", "") 'replaces (, ) and +
        Else 'if it doesn't have a plus sign
        If c.Value2 <> "" Then 'if it's not zero length
            c.Value2 = "(+" & Replace(c.Value2, " ", " +") & ")" 'replaces " " with " +" and puts the value in brackets, after the first bracket comes a plus sign as per your example
        End If
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```